# Iterating SelectedItems in a ListBox only returns the first item

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox, iteration, selecteditem

I have a databound ListBox that is behaving strangely.  The ListBox's `SelectionMode` property is set to `MultiExtended`, and on a button click, I need to copy the items to another control, in this case, a TreeView.  However, for some reason, every iterator I've tried only loops once.  I've attempted both `SelectedItems` and `SelectedIndices`.  Code excerpt:

```
var movedItems = new List<ListBoxUnderlyingObject>();
foreach (var selectedItem in listBox.SelectedItems)
{
    var castItem = selectedItem as ListBoxUnderlyingObject;
    var newNode = new TreeNode(castItem.SomeString);
    newNode.Name = castItem.AnotherString;
    newNode.Tag = castItem;
    newNode.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
    //parentNode was set earlier
    parentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
    movedItems.Add(selectedItem);
}
//use movedItems to remove items from listBox's underlying databound object and rebind
```

No matter how many items are selected, the loop only executes once.  Same with `SelectedIndices`.  If I attempt it with a numbered iterator, it fails with an "index out of bounds of array" error.

```
for(var i = 0;i < listBox.SelectedItems.Count;i++)
{
    var castItem = listBox.SelectedItems[i] as ListBoxUnderlyingObject;
    //etc., the previous line bombs on the second iteration
}
```

If I throw a `Debug.WriteLine(listBox.SelectedItems.Count)` either before or during the loop, it always reflects the correct count.  I know this is probably something stupid, but I'm stumped.  Help!

**Follow Up**

I've created a separate winforms project that emulates the behavior almost exactly, and SelectedItems works.  I am completely baffled.  Now, I'm going to try and add a new form in the original project and see if I can recreate the behavior there.

Comment: Is this the complete code? Are you binding using `DataSource` or just adding items to the ListBox? Is any removal of items occurring inside the loop? Casting an item and adding it to a list shouldn't be the sole cause of any issues.

Comment: Added the treeview code.  It is binding using a DataSource.  No, it does not remove items until after the loop is complete.

Comment: Under the debugger - if the count is 5, does it let you inspect and see listBox.SelectedItems[0-4]?

Comment: @John Arlen, no it does not.  listBox.SelectedItems[1] throws index out of range exception.  listBox.SelectedItems[0] works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out I **did** withhold some critical information.  The listbox has drag-drop behavior enabled, and part of this is a handler for the MouseDown event.  The handler has this code in it:

```
private void listBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.Items.Count = 0) return;
    listBox.DoDragDrop(listBox.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

If I comment this handler out, `SelectedItems` behaves correctly.  Now I have to figure out how to do the drag-drop stuff correctly, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

See the example [listed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode.aspx).  Instead of using selected item / items / index / indices, they recommend you iterate over each list item and use the [GetSelected Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.getselected.aspx) to determine whether the given index has been selected.

Comment: The example is not relevant for this situation. In this case, the ListBox is fed through the DataSource property so it's not possible to iterate through the items collection and use GetSelected to select an item.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and It took me to the verge of going crazy. I don't have an explanation but I have a workaround: set the DisplayMember property of the ListBox. It "should" work with the ToString() method but for some reason it does not work, so I implemented a property that returns the value of ToString and mapped the DisplayMember to that property. I wish you luck.